# Only on jenkins server : [SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I am able to run build successfully in my local but same is failing on `jenkins` server , Please let me know the solution if anyone already faces and resolved.

```
17:34:48 [1631102688.878][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
17:34:49 org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created
17:34:49 from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
17:34:49   (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)
17:34:49 Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
```

Comment: Are you adding some arguments before creating new `WebDriver` instance?

Comment: `org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException` how are you initializing the driver?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This session error are caused by following reasons,

1. Make sure you have done port connectivity between your jenkins machine and Remote machine . 8080 -> 4444
2. if you are using local driver and linux machine, make sure you have given executable/higher permission to the chromedriver.